# How to increase the tabindex in React ul-li search result?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I used `ul li` to implement search result:

```
<ul className="search-result">
  <li tabindex="1">title here...</li>
  <li tabindex="2">title here...</li>
  <li tabindex="3">title here...</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

and this is the style for each item:

```
.search-result{
 li:active, li:focuse {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f0f0f0;
 }
}
```

but I'm trying to add a feature which client navigate between result items by using key-down or key-up buttons on the keyboard. but how can I access to current active `tabindex` in document to increase or decrease that by JavaScript and not `tab` button?

Comment: Create a state variable which keeps track of the current tab.

Comment: @HritikSharma but how can i apply that state to UL's children?

Comment: Are these results meant to have an action? i.e. can we click on a result in order to perform an action. And if that is the case, does the click result in navigation or in an action on the same page. If not then there is no need for a `tabindex` as they should not be interactive. If they are interactive then we just need the appropriate element (a button or anchor) within the list item. Let me know and I will drop an answer including a super simple way to have key navigation (as well as correct markup)!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to <kbd>tab</kbd> to each `<li>` (search result) **and** use the up/down arrow keys to navigate through the list?

You have to be careful when using positive values for `tabindex`.  It should *rarely* be used because it changes the default browser focus order which most users are used to.  The default focus order is DOM order.  In your case, if you want the user to <kbd>tab</kbd> to each `<li>` in order, you **don't** need a positive value for `tabindex` because your `<li>` elements are already in the order you want them tabbed to.  Just set them all to 0.  A value of 0 means that the DOM element should be inserted into the tab order in the normal DOM order.

```
<ul className="search-result">
  <li tabindex="0">title here...</li>
  <li tabindex="0">title here...</li>
  <li tabindex="0">title here...</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

Now, having said that, elements should only have `tabindex="0"` if they are *interactive* elements. An `<li>` is not normally an interactive element so it'll be confusing to tab to it.  What can the user do once they tab to the `<li>`?  Can they press <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> to select it?  If the user can't interact with that element, then it should not be a tab stop.

Typically, the `<li>` contains things that *are* interactive, such as links, buttons, checkboxes, etc.  Those elements are already tab stops by default and don't need a `tabindex`.

As far as using up/down arrow keys for navigation, again, you should only be able to arrow to elements that are interactive.  I normally have an `onkeydown` handler on the `<ul>` and it listens for the arrow keys and adjusts the tabindex for each item.  But I only do this when I want my entire list to be **one tab stop** and the user must arrow up/down to go between each list item.  In your case, it sounds like you want both behaviors which is why I asked the question at the beginning of my answer.

If the list is treated as one tab stop, then all `<li>` elements will have a `tabindex="-1"` **except** for the `<li>` that has focus.  It will have `tabindex="0"`.  That way the user can <kbd>tab</kbd> to the list *as a whole* and the focus will go to the list item that last had focus.  The user can then up/down through the list.

When the user presses up/down, all you have to do is change `tabindex` from 0 to -1 for the currently focused list item and change `tabindex` from -1 to 0 for the list item you're moving focus to, and then call `focus()` on the newly focused element.

Answer (score 1):

You need store current tab index in state and update it in keydown eventListener

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import users from "./data";

export default function App() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);
  const searchResults = users.filter(
    (user) => searchValue.trim() && user.includes(searchValue.trim())
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
      const keyCode = e.keyCode;
      if (keyCode == 38 && searchResults.length - 1 > currentTab)
        setCurrentTab(currentTab + 1);
      if (keyCode == 40 && currentTab >= 1) setCurrentTab(currentTab - 1);
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, [searchResults, currentTab]);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
          setCurrentTab(0);
        }}
      />
      <ul className="search-result">
        {searchResults.map((result, i) => (
          <li className={currentTab === i ? "active" : ""}>{result}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-surf-fxj1z?file=/src/App.js:0-1177), you can check it

Comment: @MartinRützy you can detect enter keycode and get current result from current tab index, i updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-surf-fxj1z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: but there is another problem, what shall I do for scrollable list? suppose that, I added `scroll-y: auto` and `max-height: 150px` for the results `ul` you solution doesn't change scroll position!

Comment: apparently i have to use HTML tabindex attribute to make it easier... ?

Comment: @MartinRützy you should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864901/how-to-scroll-to-li-element-in-a-ul-list/12874891), you can see it in my [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-surf-fxj1z?file=/src/App.js),